# to merge two columns in a csv file

Tags: python, csv

merge two columns in a csv file

Comment: give more details , some code !

Comment: What do you mean with *merge* ? Just remove the separator?

Comment: ya remove the separator and place the values in both columns as a single column

Comment: i ve done this...
import csv

reader=csv.reader(open("project-table.csv","rb"),delimiter=" ")
writer=csv.writer(open("output.csv","wb"))


name1=[]
for data in reader:
        print data[2]
        name1=data[2]+data[43]
        writer.writerow(name1)

Comment: sorry.. how to post code in this??

Comment: @Anand: change `name1=data[2]+data[43]` to `name1=data[2].strip()+'.'+data[43].strip()` and `writer.writerow(name1)` to `writer.writerow((name1, None))`

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example, dont know your delimiter. if you want to write it to the same file you have to buffer the whole file first, modify the rows, then write it back to the same file.

```
 import csv
 for row in csv.reader(open('test.txt'),delimiter="\t"):
     print row[0]+row[1]
```

Comment: hi thnx a lot really.... just another small doubt.. wat if i wanna add a dot(.) between the 2 concatenated strings??

Comment: and how do i write this concatenated column to a new csv file??

Answer (score 0):

```
    fin = open('file.csv', 'r+')
    fout = open('NEW.csv','w')
    for line in fin.xreadlines():
        new = line.replace(',', ' ', 1)
        fout.write (new)
    fin.close()
    fout.close()
```

Assuming that "file.csv" is the input, and "NEW.csv" is the output. Also the first comma is getting replaced by space. You can alter that by modifying

> new = line.replace(',', ' ', 1)

and replacing the second argument with anything you want

Comment: this will merge all the columns in the file... i wanna merge only 2 specific columns...  say col[3] and column [10].. how do i do tht?? please help... please :(